# How to correctly pattern match the beginning of the line and replace it with two characters using sed

Tags: macos, sed

I'm trying to turn the following:

```
## Features
feature:foo
feature: baz
```

into:

```
## Features
- feature:foo
- feature: baz
```

I came up with this structure:

```
sed -i '' 's/^[^#]/- /' $1
```

but that results in:

```
## Features
- eature:foo
- eature: baz
```

FWIW my *sed* command would have worked fine if I was just trying to add it to the beginning of the line without doing any checks for `#`, but when I do a pattern match, it eats through one of the existing characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use one of these `sed` solution:

```bash
sed 's/^[^#]/- &/' file
# or
sed '/^#/! s/^/- /' file

## Features
- feature:foo
- feature: baz
```

To save changes inline on Mac OSX (BSD sed) use:

```bash
sed -i '' 's/^[^#]/- &/' file
sed -i '' '/^#/! s/^/- /' file
```

Note that `sed 's/^[^#]/- &/' file` uses `&` in replacement to put matched character back in output string so that that character matched by `[^#]` is put back in substitution.

Comment: Awesome. How come your other answer doesn't require `&` ? And just to be clear, the `!` is about negating _addresses_?

Comment: In the second sed I am just matching start position after matching a line that doesn’t start with # So & will be an empty string in this case